# JSF Inject multiple beans into a backing-bean

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I'm injecting two beans inside my backing bean with `ManagedProperty`. The backing bean is view scope and the model bean is request scope that looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "categoryBB")
@ViewScoped
public class CategoryBackingBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -880184144170934066L;
private static final Logger LOG = Logger
        .getLogger(CategoryBackingBean.class);

@ManagedProperty("#{categoryService}")
CategoryService categoryService;

@ManagedProperty("#{categoryBean}")
CategoryBean categoryBean;

//Getters/Setters...
}
```

However I'm receiving the following error:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to create managed bean categoryBB`.

The following problems were found:

```
The scope of the object referenced by expression #{categoryBean}, request, is shorter than the referring managed beans (categoryBB) scope of view
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
```

My web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
     </param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Enable Spring-Security TagLib in JSF -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.ae/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingRequestParametersInAViewScopedBean Check this post, might help you.

Comment: I believe it has been fixed if you can update to newest JSF version

Comment: You don't tell what kind of beans are the ones you want to inject. As you tag `Spring` in the question, are you trying to inject Spring beans there? If there are JSF managed beans, you must guarantee they are at least `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: I'm using ManagedBeans and ManagedProperty only. The categoryBean is a Request bean and the categoryService is a @Service.
My JSF version is 2.2.6.

Comment: How did u configure `web.xml` for `JSF + Spring` integration?